# How do I get an attached file from CosmosDB using Nodejs SDK?

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to work with CosmosDB in Nodejs.  I have created some Documents in a collection and have added a couple attachments to one of the documents like so:

```
let dbds = new azure(dbEndpoint, {"masterKey":dbKey})
fs.open("c:/temp/capture.png", "r", (err, fd) => {
   if(err) console.log(err);
   else{
      dbds.createAttachmentAndUploadMedia(documentLink, fs, {contentType:"image/png", partitionKey: partitionKey}, (err, result) =>{
        fs.close(fd);
        if(err) console.log(err);
        else console.log(result);

        }
   }
}
```

Now when I read that attachments for that document, I get 2 attachments:

```
dbds.readAttachments(documentLink, {"partitionKey":partitionKey}).toArray((err, result) => {
  if(err) console.log(err);
  else {
    console.log(result.length);  //2
    result.forEach(i => console.log(i.id);)  //id of each attachment
  }
}
```

Now I need to be able to read the document back and store it locally.  There doesn't seem to be any documentation that I can find for doing this in Nodejs.  I've tried the following:

```
let attachment = result[0];  //from result of toArray() above -- first attachment from list
let mediaURI = `${attachment._self}${attachment.media}`
dbds.readMedia(mediaURI, (err, result) => {
    if(err) console.log(JSON.parse(err.body).message); //Request url is invalid
    else {
        //try to write result to file
    }
}
```

How do I create a valid URI to the media in order to download it?

**Edit**

Based on comments below, I updated my code as follows:

```
let attachment = result[0]
let mediaURI = attachment.media  //here is the change
dbds.readMedia(mediaURI, (err, result) => {
    if(err) console.log(JSON.parse(err.body).message);
    else {
      //try to store the data
    }
})
```

I no longer get an error but instead get a JSON object:

```
"{"constants":{"O_RDONLY":0,"O_WRONLY":1,"O_RDWR":2,"S_IFMT"‌​:61440,"S_IFREG":327‌​68,"S_IFDIR":16384,"‌​S_IFCHR":8192,"S_IFL‌​NK":40960,"O_CREAT":‌​256,"O_EXCL":1024,"O‌​_TRUNC":512,"O_APPEN‌​D":8,"F_OK":0,"R_OK"‌​:4,"W_OK":2,"X_OK":1‌​},"F_OK":0,"R_OK":4,‌​"W_OK":2,"X_OK":1}"
```

Comment: There should be a link/URL to it in the attachments that are returned so `console.log(i)` rather than `console.log(i.id)`

Comment: The only link I see to the media is what I've shown above in the last code sample.  `i._self` is a link to the attachment.  `i.media` appears to be a uri to the media data -- except it gives me an error if I use it -- again, see my last code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help from some folks at Microsoft on this.

The primary issue was that I wasn't writing the file correctly.

Instead of this

```
let dbds = new azure(dbEndpoint, {"masterKey":dbKey})
fs.open("c:/temp/capture.png", "r", (err, fd) => {
   if(err) console.log(err);
   else{
      dbds.createAttachmentAndUploadMedia(documentLink, fs, {contentType:"image/png", partitionKey: partitionKey}, (err, result) =>{
        fs.close(fd);
        if(err) console.log(err);
        else console.log(result);

        }
   }
}
```

With `fs.open` fs is not a filestream -- which is what `createAttachmentAndUploadMedia` is looking for.  I had mistakenly assumed that fs was a fs.open created a filestream.

What I wound up doing was the following:

```
fs.readFile("c:/temp/myimage.jpg",(err, data) => {
    if(err) reject(err);
    else dbds.svc.createAttachmentAndUploadMedia(docPath,data,{contentType: "image/jpeg"
         , partitionKey: "Key"}, (err, result) =>{..}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the mediaURI should just be ${attachment.media} not concatenated with the ${attachment._self}.

Here is an snippet:

```
return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    this.documentDbClient.readAttachment(docLink, options, (err, result) => {
        if (err)
            return reject(err);

        resolve(result.media);
    });
}).then((medialink) => {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        this.documentDbClient.readMedia(medialink, (err, result) => {
            if (err)
                return reject(err);

            // buffered data    
            const data = [];
            result.on('data', (chunk) => data.push(chunk));

            result.on('end', () => {
                resolve(data.join(''));
            });

            // if not buffered
            // resolve(result.toString());
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That helped -- I no longer get back an error, but now I get back a JSON string `"{"constants":{"O_RDONLY":0,"O_WRONLY":1,"O_RDWR":2,"S_IFMT":61440,"S_IFREG":32768,"S_IFDIR":16384,"S_IFCHR":8192,"S_IFLNK":40960,"O_CREAT":256,"O_EXCL":1024,"O_TRUNC":512,"O_APPEND":8,"F_OK":0,"R_OK":4,"W_OK":2,"X_OK":1},"F_OK":0,"R_OK":4,"W_OK":2,"X_OK":1}"` rather than my binary data.

Comment: My connectionPolicy is set to MediaReadMode Buffered so I was expecting an array of data

Comment: Sorry, I assumed the file was just a text string. If the result is buffered, I believe you just need to add subscribers to the event. I edited my response with untested code.

Comment: Error: result.on is not a function.  Tried casting result to an object `JSON.parse(result)` as well.  That effectively turns the string above into an object -- but no, `on()` functions.  Are you aware of any documentation on CosmosDB media anywhere?

Comment: Rodd, we are looking into this issue and will post the solution here.